# Can baby farmer villagers farm?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was wondering if a baby farmer villager can plant and grow crops, just like a adult farmer does.  I would appreciate an answer.Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**No, they cannot.**

This is because they have a different AI behavior than a grown up Villager. This is also the reason why you can't trade with baby Villagers.

However, if you have the patience to wait for 20 minutes or so, they'll grow up and they will be able to farm and trade.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I know that baby farmer villagers cannot farm or trade, just like other baby villagers:-)